# How to load different view in joomla controller?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have simple line, but it doesn't work.

```
$this->getView($input->get('my_wiew', 'Sites', 'CMD'), 'HTML');
//some code
parent::display();
```

If i simple go to the url `index.php?option=com_my_component&view=sites` i get my view, but by default it doesn't want to load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$view   = $this->getView('view_name', 'html'); //get the view
$view->assignRef('data', $data_from_model); // assign data from the model
$view->display(); // display the view
```

[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJController/getView)

Comment: in this case in view.html.php  `$this->getModel()` doesn't work

Comment: $model  = $this->getModel('model_name'); try this

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: sites in /Users/nonamez/Sites/joomla/libraries/joomla/application/component/view.php on line 413 Fatal error: Call to a member function getSites() on a non-object in /Users/nonamez/Sites/joomla/components/com_mycomponent/views/sites/view.HTML.php on line 13`

Comment: `$model = $this->getModel('sites');
$sites = $model->getSites();`

Comment: This is due to there is no getSites() method in the sites model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19324/discussion-between-dasun-and-user1692333)